# multiple layer of forwardRef and useImperativeHandle

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I need to use `ref` to get a grandchild component's state, and I customized it by using `useImperativeHandle`, the whole code is simplified
[here](https://codesandbox.io/s/useimperativehandle-jfdnt?file=/src/App.js).

```
function App() {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={() => console.log(ref.current.name, ref.current.age)}
      >click me</button>
      <FilterFather ref={ref} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
const FilterFather = (_, ref) => {
  const filter1Ref = useRef(null);
  const filter2Ref = useRef(null);
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    name: filter1Ref.current.name,
    age: filter2Ref.current.age,
  }))
  return (
    <>
      <Filter1 ref={filter1Ref}/>
      <Filter2 ref={filter2Ref} />
    </>
  )
}
export default forwardRef(FilterFather);
```

```
const Filter1 = (props, ref) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('lewis')
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    name
  }), [name])
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        name:
        <input 
          value={name}
          onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
const Filter2 = (props, ref) => {
  const [age, setAge] = useState(18)
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    age
  }), [age])
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        age:
        <input 
          value={age}
          onChange={e => setAge(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
export default {
  Filter1: forwardRef(Filter1),
  Filter2: forwardRef(Filter2),
}
```

one layer of `forwardRef` and `useImperativeHandle` works fine, two layers went wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your imperative handle in `FilterFather` is not required. It doesn't add/remove anything to the handle. You can just forward it directly:

```
const FilterFather = (_, ref) => {
  return <Filter ref={ref} />;
};
```

[image: Edit useImperativeHandle]

Also there is a problem with it because it will not update correctly.

```
useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    name: filterRef.current.name,
    age: filterRef.current.age,
}), [filterRef]) // this will not update correctly
```

You passed `filterRef` as a dependency but `filterRef` is static and will not change even when `filterRef.current.name` or `filterRef.current.age` changes.

Note that `useImperativeHandle` is not supposed to be used to read state from child components. It is actually discouraged to use any kind of imperative methods in react except there is no other way. This is most of the time the case if you work with 3rd party libraries that are imperative in nature.

**EDIT**:

Given your updated code the react way to do that is to lift state up. It doesn't require any refs:

```
export default function App() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    name: "lewis",
    age: 18
  });

  const handleChange = useCallback(
    (key, value) => setValues(current => ({ ...current, [key]: value })),
    []
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => console.log(values.name, values.age)}>
        click me
      </button>
      <FilterFather values={values} onChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
const FilterFather = props => {
  return (
    <>
      <Filter label="Name" name="name" {...props} />
      <Filter label="Age" name="age" {...props} />
    </>
  );
};
```

```
const Filter = ({ label, name, values, onChange }) => {
  const handleChange = useCallback(e => onChange(name, e.target.value), [
    name,
    onChange
  ]);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <label>{label}:</label>
        <input value={values[name]} onChange={handleChange} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit useImperativeHandle]

Comment: in fact in the dependency array, I tried `[filterRef,current.name, filterRef.current.age]`, but eslint said unnecessary dependencies,

Comment: @crazyones110 That is because changes on refs do not trigger component updates so react has no chance to even check if they updated. So properties of refs are not suitable as dependencies in general. It's generally just a flawed approach to try to pass state up the tree. A strength and key feature of react is that data always flows down, not up. There is very likely a better way to achieve what you are trying to do. I guess that you should lift the state up and pass it to the inputs to make them controlled.

Comment: already edited the question to suit the real example

Comment: @crazyones110 See my updated answer for an approach that doesn't require any refs.

Comment: what if I have to use multiple useImperativeHandle, how should I handle it

Comment: @crazyones110 Generally imperative handles or refs in general should be avoided whenever possible. Those features exist only for purposes where you have no choice but to use them in order to achieve your requirements. I don't know enough about your use case to answer that. You mean multiple `useImperativeHandle`s in one component?